# Use specific exception type in @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-error-handling) draws an example on how to setup an `@ExceptionHandler` in a web app. This `@ExceptionHandler` targets a specific exception, `YourException`, but the method parameter uses `Throwable`. Is this necessary or a "bug" in the docs?

```java
@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<?> handleControllerException(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
    HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new CustomErrorType(status.value(), ex.getMessage()), status);
}
```

Changing the type of the method parameter to the specific type works in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work, adding Throwable will help in case you want to handle more than one exception with a single method and you want to access something out of throwable instance. This will even work without adding any parameter. It's not a bug, we can use it as per our need. Look at the below code snippet.

```
@RestController
```

public class TestController {

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getGreeetings() {
    //throw new NullPointerException("exception");
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}


@ExceptionHandler({NullPointerException.class, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class})
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex){
    //here ex.getMessage() or any other logic you can use
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("internal server error", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    
}
```

}

This is not as per the best practice ideally we should handle it separately. Sometimes we do prefer to return a common message where this can be useful.